# behavior of pc in armv7a assembly and in ucontext_t

Tags: exception, assembly, arm, signal-handling

If you have the armv7a assembly instruction:

```
400000: e59fc008      ldr     r2, [pc, #4]
```

This loads the value at `40000c` (so `r2=*(pc+12)` rather than `r2=*(pc+4)`).   This is due to the pipeline which points two instructions ahead when reading.  I'm wondering how this works in conjunction the ucontext of a signal handler.

When you enter a signal handler, ucontext is supposed to house the register state at the point of the exception.   But, ucontext.mcontext.arm_pc points to the actual instruction which caused the exception.   So would I have to add 8 to this register to simulate the actual register state?   Are there any other registers which would need to be adjusted?

Comment: It does not really work like that in general.  `pc` only points 8 bytes ahead for some instructions whereas for others its value is correct.  It is easier to think of this as there being an offset that is added to `pc` when it is operand to certain instructions.  The ARM architecture reference manual has a full explanation of the behaviour of `pc` as an operand to each possible instruction.

Comment: Can you give me an example of an instruction where it is considered to be correct?   In `Reading the Program Counter`, The arm spec says: `For an ARM instruction, the value read is the address of the instruction plus 8 bytes ...`

Comment: Sorry, I was mistaken here.  Indeed `PC` is read with an offset of +8 on current variants of the architecture (+12 used to be allowed as an alternative before ARMv7).  I was thinking of instructions like `BL` which move the address of the next instruction to LR without applying the offset.

Comment: It is not pc+12 it is pc+4.   the program counter is 8 bytes a head of the instruction address so pc+4 = instruction address + 12.   please dont get the two confused.  In arm mode, in thumb mode it is 4 bytes ahead, two instructions in both cases.

Comment: understand that there are multiple program counters, it really isnt one thing, at this point it is more of a notion.  the instruction set has a definition (that the address used for r15 is two instructions ahead of the starting address of the instruction at the time of execution).

Comment: what @old_timer told. So when you entering exception handler caused by 'execution', you do pc-8. When you entering prefetch abort handler, you do pc-4 (prefetch stage is before execution stage, pc could not go that far)

Comment: Currently the signal handler is triggered by a timer, but I was going to connect it to an exception handler as well.   For the timer, I believe the arm_pc points to the instruction which was being executed at the time of interrupt (please correct me if I'm wrong on this) -- are you suggesting this may differ depending on what kind of exception occurred?

Comment: If I look [here](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/it-infrastructure/dev-signal-handlers-studio.html), for listing 8, it implies that mcontext->arm_pc points to the instruction that caused the exception (not 8 bytes ahead).

Comment: `handle_prof_signal(int sig_no, siginfo_t* info, void *vcontext)` parameters could not be passed to interrupt/exception handler... that implies that this handler is a sort of user callback which is called from 'real' exception handler. What that exception handler is putting in parameters is totally different question and answer depends on OS running. If you want to understand how pipelining affects PC register, search for "arm pipeline fetch decode execute"